# vba function: return string with newline

Tags: excel, vba

first of all, new to VBA.

I am implementing this solution [how-to-merge-all-column-into-one-cell-in-excel[stackoverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135995/how-to-merge-all-column-into-one-cell-in-excel), but have a follow-on.

```
A1:I
A2:am
A3:a
A4:boy
```

my output is: `Iamaboy` but I would like in one cell:

```
I
am
a
boy
```

Functions do not seem to return strings with `vbNewLine`, `chr(10)` or `chr(13)`...

Comment: you need to set `wrap text` of your cell manually in Excel, too.

Comment: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=16059

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line of code:

```
Range("B1").Formula = join(application.transpose(Range("A1:A4")),vblf)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, as tlewin said

```
=ConcatenateRange(A1:A4,CHAR(10))
```

Or alternatively, using [alt-enter] you could write it like this

```
=ConcatenateRange(A1:A4,"
")
```

"But wait," you say, "I tried that and it does not work!"
Well, you see, when you manually enter something like `I[alt-enter]am[alt-enter]a[alt-enter]boy` in Excel, or even execute a statement such as `[A1] = "I" & vbNewLine & "am"` Excel automatically changes the cells formatting and turns on word wrap. Word wrap is **required** for linebreaks to be shown in a cell. However if you return a string with a linebreak in it from a UDF Excel does not update the format.

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Manually enable word wrap on any cell you use this function in
2. (Not recommended) Store the reference in `Application.Caller` during your ConcatenateRange UDF call, then set an `Application.OnTime(now, "AddWordWrap")` call and write the AddWordWrap subroutine so that it uses the stored reference to add the wordwrap formatting to the cell (this is because you cannot update the cell's format in a UDF). This method is buggy and problematic.

Comment: Your additional information on word warp is spot on. This is a limitation of excel. I must live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the CHAR(10) separator:

```
=ConcatenateRange(A1:A4;CHAR(10))
```

Comment: I'd definitely upvote this as it seems that it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @DanielCook Did you try CHAR(13)? And you recalculate the worksheet (F9)?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=A1&"[Alt+Enter]"&A2&"[Alt+Enter]"&A3&"[Alt+Enter]"&A4
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "sgar" & Chr(10) & "saha"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cells(row, column) = "current line" & Chr(10) & "new line"
```

Answer (score -1):

I stuck this in and it did work once I used 'wrap text'.