# Using concatenate and decode in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a  column having values as

```
A
1.decode(D01,1,1,3,3,4)
2.decode (d02,1,1,3,3,4)
3.decode(d03,1,1,3,3,4)
...
...
31.decode(d31,1,1,3,3,4)
```

and i  need to have these columns in a string seperated by comma as

`decode(D01,1,1,3,3,4), decode (d02,1,1,3,3,4), decode(d03,1,1,3,3,4)`

and so forth up to 31 such values in a comma separated list.

How will I be able to do this in excel?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. It sounds like the values in your Column A are exactly what you want? Read your own question:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `CONCATENATE` over all the rows like:

`=CONCATENATE(A1&", "&A2&", "&A3&", "&A4&", "&A5&", "&A6&", "&A7&", "&A8&", "&A9&", "&A10&", "&A11&", "&A12&", "&A13&", "&A14&", "&A15&", "&A16&", "&A17&", "&A18&", "&A19&", "&A20&", "&A21&", "&A22&", "&A23&", "&A24&", "&A25&", "&A26&", "&A27&", "&A28&", "&A29&", "&A30&", "&A31)`

Or You can create and use something like the `ConcatenateRange` presented [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8136346/2745633)

Or You can do:

1. Set cell B1 to "=A1"
2. Set cell B2 to "=B1&", "&A2"
3. Copy cell B2 all the way down to B31

Cell B31 will now contain the concatenated text string you are looking for.
[image]

Comment: I know of concatenate and one by one input of arguments list . but this is something i was trying not to do .

Comment: Then try the alternative I suggested

Comment: @manimatters the link to the answer you provided answers the OP's question. +1

Comment: I have added a third alternative