# Concatenate cells from multiple sheets in Excel

Tags: excel

I’m trying to use [How to merge rows in a column into one cell in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135995/how-to-merge-all-column-into-one-cell-in-excel) to make

```
=ConcatenateRange(sheet1:sheet2!B1,",")
```

but it doesn't seem to work. What comes back from `sheet1:sheet2!B1`? Is it a range, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the UDF is designed to accept a single **Range** as input (*which may consist of multiple cells*).  A **Range** is limited to cells on a single sheet.  You need to modify the UDF to handle multiple ranges.