# How to ignore filtered-out data in Excel formula

Tags: excel

I am using an Index/Match to get data from a related table to populate in the first table. In my related table I have filtered out values, but the filtered out values are still populating in my first table. If Index/Match is not smart enough to only grab the filtered values, how can I work around this (formula preferred, but VBA acceptable) to get only the filtered values.

Here is my current formula:

```
=INDEX(Table_owssvr__1[MyValues],MATCH([@[ID]],Table_owssvr__1[ID],0))
```

Comment: =INDEX(Table_owssvr__1[MyValues],MATCH([@[ID]],Table_owssvr__1[ID],0))

Comment: press the edit button and put that in the question

Comment: I think the way excel formulas get data from hidden areas is smart not the other way around. It means we can hid our workings and still have formulas which reference those hidden areas.

Comment: You'll have to add the filter criteria to your index/match formula, so that it knows what to ignore

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this?

Comment: You would need to provide more context for that. What is the table filtered on? Share a data sample.

Comment: Users will change the filter as they please so the context would be any of the 5 column headers. This is using the built in filter that comes with a table in Excel. Thanks to everyone for the help

Comment: The INDEX and MATCH functions cannot access the visible status of the cells, so if those functions are required, you would need VBA.

Comment: Do you have any VBA or examples you can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to get this working by the following:

1) Create three worksheets, one for clients, one for purchases, and one for purchasesforclient.

2) Create a Macro to copy filtered values to a new worksheet:

```
Sub Purchases()
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Worksheets("Comments").Columns("A")
Set Rng = Rng.Resize(65535, 1).Offset(1, 0)
Set Rng = Rng.Resize(, 5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Rng.Copy Worksheets("PurchasesforClient").Range("A2")
End Sub
```

3) When I update the purchases via a filter, I run the macro in step 2 by creating a subtotal field and triggering the macro as follows. Since it is a formula, it requires a calculation to occur. This is embedded in the purchases sheet as VBA where the filtering is occurring, where B23 is the subtotal field that changes when it counts the amount of items once a filter is applied:

```
Public CurrentValue As Double

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
CurrentValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet.Range("B23"))
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B23")) <> CurrentValue Then Purchases
End Sub
```

4) I use the now filtered values in the purchasesforclient worksheet for my index/match formula in the clients worksheet. This allows me to dynamically filter by date, purchase type, etc. and have updated information in the clients worksheet

Answer (score 2):

You might find the [`SUBTOTAL`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/subtotal-function-HP010062463.aspx) function useful, as it only works on  visible rows. ([Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-sum-values-in-an-excel-filtered-list/)'s some more general discussion about `SUBTOTAL`)

But if that's not flexible enough for your needs, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173445/excel-vba-filtered-visible-cell) how to check whether a certain cell is filtered out or not.

Using this, I've written a bit of VBA code to sum over a column summing only visible cells. Should be a pretty useful start in doing whatever you need to do.

If summing over the cells is not what you want to do, just change the part indicated in the comments. (Obviously you'd have to change the name of the function from `sumFilteredColumn` to something else!)

```
Public Function sumFilteredColumn(startCell As Range)

    Dim lastRow As Long ' the last row of the worksheet which startCell is on
    Dim currentCell As Range
    Dim runningTotal As Long ' keeps track of the sum so far

    lastRow = lastRowOnSheet(startCell)
    Set currentCell = startCell

    ' Loop until the last row of the worksheet
    Do While currentCell.Row <= lastRow
        ' Check currentCell is not hidden
        If Not cellIsOnHiddenRow(currentCell) Then
            ' -------------------------------------------------
            ' Here's where the magic happens. Change this to
            ' change sum to, e.g. concatenate or multiply etc.
            If IsNumeric(currentCell.Value) Then
                runningTotal = runningTotal + currentCell.Value
            End If
            ' -------------------------------------------------
        End If
        Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(1) ' Move current cell down
    Loop

    sumFilteredColumn = runningTotal

End Function

' return the number of the last row in the UsedRange
' of the sheet referenceRange appears in
Public Function lastRowOnSheet(referenceRange As Range) As Long

    Dim referenceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim referenceUsedRange As Range
    Dim usedRangeCellCount As Long
    Dim lastCell As Range

    Set referenceSheet = referenceRange.Parent
    Set referenceUsedRange = referenceSheet.usedRange
    usedRangeCellCount = referenceUsedRange.Cells.CountLarge

    Set lastCell = referenceUsedRange(usedRangeCellCount)
    lastRowOnSheet = lastCell.Row

End Function

' Is the row which referenceCell is on hidden by a filter?
Public Function cellIsOnHiddenRow(referenceCell As Range) As Boolean

    Dim referenceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rowNumber As Long

    Set referenceSheet = referenceCell.Parent
    rowNumber = referenceCell.Row

    cellIsOnHiddenRow = referenceSheet.Rows(rowNumber).EntireRow.Hidden

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

LondonRob mentioned the [SUBTOTAL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) function. [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) is a more general function than SUBTOTAL that operates with knowledge of both hidden and filtered cells (there is a difference). They'll do that without addins or VBA, though with somewhat hard-to-read formulae.

I learnt it from [here](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/visible-column-in-excel-tables.htm).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer requires MOREFUNC addon***

`=INDEX(ARRAY.FILTER(Table_owssvr__1[MyValues]),MATCH([@[ID]],ARRAY.FILTER(Table_owssvr__1[ID]),0))`

[`ARRAY.FILTER()` function](http://web.archive.org/web/20111024033333/http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english/tab.filtre.htm) "Stores only the visible cells of a range (for instance a filtered range) in an array and returns this array. "

---

***MOREFUNC ADDON**

- Morefunc Addon is a free library of 66 new worksheet functions.
- [HERE](http://web.archive.org/web/20111204011358/http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english) is some information (by original author)
- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)

Comment: That download link is not to the original author website. I would not trust a random download site like this to have clean files. This add-on only works in Excel 2007 and prior. Looks like you may have to "reinvent this wheel" in the latest versions of Excel.

Comment: Sources NOT available.  Hidden.