# Combine several columns into one cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a situation where I have 123 columns of data and out of those 123 colums, only up to 6 of them will be poplated with data. I need to collect all the fields that do have data and put them into one cell.

I found this article, [How to merge rows in a column into one cell in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135995/how-to-merge-all-column-into-one-cell-in-excel),  on stackoverflow but it still is not quite what I am looking for and I could not get the =transpose solution to work as suggested at the bottom of the thread. I found a 3rd party solution that was a plugin for Excel but it is only for Windows and I have Office for Mac.

So I desperately need to know how to do this. I'am not showing 123 columns but I think you get the idea. 
http://grab.by/BwDu

=concatenate(text,text,text...) is not an option because even if I wanted to put all 123 fields in here i am still faced with the problem of the formula putting in a space or comma in place of a blank field.

Answer (score 1):

The **ConcatenateRange** function at the link you posted seems to accomplish what you want.

If you prefer a formula, this works for your example data:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
  TRIM(
   B1&" "&C1&" "&D1&" "&E1&" "&F1&" "&G1&" "&H1&" "&I1&" "&J1&" "&
   K1&" "&L1&" "&M1&" "&N1&" "&O1&" "&P1&" "&Q1&" "&R1&" "&S1
  ),
  " ",
  ","
 )
```

**Output:**

```
cat,bird,dog,mouse,horse,elephant,chimp,lion,sloth,zebra,geraf,snake,grasshopper
```

This formula concatenates the data with spaces.  `TRIM` changes multiple spaces to single spaces, and `SUBSTITUTE` replaces all the spaces with commas.

To reach 123 columns, you'll simply need to continue adding cells.