# Concatenate different rows based on same reference

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

```
Emp     #     Name
134765  Sila  Sahoo
134766  Sila  Sahoo
134767  Sila  Sahoo
```

For the data above, using formula, how can I get the output below?

`134765`, `134766`, `134767`

Comment: What is the output you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using VBA or excel formula:

For VBA, check the answer from **Jean-François Corbett** in this link: [How to merge rows in a column into one cell in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135995/how-to-merge-all-column-into-one-cell-in-excel)

For Excel Formula, check the below steps:

1) `=CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(A2:A5))` where A2:A5 contains the Employee numbers.

2) After entering the formula, dont press enter. Instead select `TRANSPOSE(A2:A5)` and press F9.

3) Now remove curly braces and press enter and you get what you want.

Comment: see I am looking for different output.