# Concatenation issue with excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

Having a little issue with excel at the moment, maybe there is a better way to do this but currently cannot think of a way to do it.

SO i am looking to concatenate values between varied row numbers, example:

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/jtt1ub.jpg]

So my first concatenation is `=concatenate(transpose(i2:i26))` ->press f9
and then the next one `=concatenate(transpose(i27:i42))` -> f9
etc

however, when i drag the box down, it seems to populate random values. IS there a fast way to concatenate the information based off varied row numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to merge all column into one cell in excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135995/how-to-merge-all-column-into-one-cell-in-excel)

Comment: Concatenate will not work on multi-cell ranges or arrays.  In general, it will only return the first element.  You will need a VBA solution, of which there have been many posted.  Work something up, then post back if you run into trouble.

Comment: At the moment all the issues i have tried do not seem to work. I have tried transpose, and tried a simple =A1:A100 and then pressing F9, which, works, but doing this manually per row is imposssible considering i have over 100,000 rows of data