# Reduce amount of dimensions in an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have  Range(one dimensional), that I want to summarize in one cell by concatenating all values. I thought that I could do just:

```
Dim Data_array()
Dim Source_Range as Range

Set Source_Range = Selection
Data_array() = Source_Range.Value2
Source_range.Offset( -1 ,0).Value = Join(Data_array, ", ")
```

This however returns `error 5` because `Data_array` is a ( 1 To X, 1 To 1) array it has two dimensions, and `Join` on last line requires that you provide just one dimenstional array.

So my question would be is there a way to remove that "1 To 1" dimension?
If not how would you concatenate a one dimensional range in one cell.

Example

```
     A
1    
2    2
3    4
4    6
```

Desired Result

```
     A
1    2, 4, 6
2    2
3    4
4    6
```

Comment: Would this work? `Redim Data_Array(1 to X)`

Comment: "Script out of Range." Error 9 Thanks though

Comment: Well you need to define X, which I thought you had, since you used it in your example. `X = Source_Range.Count Redim Data_array(1 to x)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to merge all column into one cell in excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135995/how-to-merge-all-column-into-one-cell-in-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close! The code below assumes you will select the cells below the empty target cell. I't is simply two tweaks from your original code:

```
Sub testing()

    Dim Data_array()
    Dim Source_Range As Range

    Set Source_Range = Selection
    Data_array() = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Source_Range.Value2)
    Source_Range.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(1, 1).Value = Join(Data_array, ", ")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For your data, I would not bother with a *VBA* array.  Consider:

```
Public Function Konkat(rin As Range) As String
    For Each r In rin
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" Then
            Konkat = Konkat & "," & v
        End If
    Next r
    Konkat = Right(Konkat, Len(Konkat) - 1)
End Function
```

[image]

This is because in your code, *data_Array* is actually a **two-dimensional** array.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an idea. NOTE: I'm not sure that the `OFFSET` part of your code does what you want it to do. Test the code, and let me know if so.

```
Dim Data_array()
Dim Source_Range As Range
Dim nIncrement As Integer

Set Source_Range = Selection
nIncrement = 1

ReDim Data_array(1 To Source_Range.Rows.Count)
For Each cel In Source_Range
    Data_array(nIncrement) = cel.Value
    nIncrement = nIncrement + 1
Next cel

Source_Range.Offset(-1, 0).Value = Join(Data_array, ", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the INDEX worksheet function to slice out a column or row.

```
Sub JoinRangeComma()

    Dim vaData As Variant
    Dim rSource As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set rSource = Selection
    vaData = rSource.Value2
    rSource.Cells(1).Offset(-1, 0).Value = Join(wf.Index(wf.Transpose(vaData), 1, 0), ", ")

End Sub
```