# Merge or concatenate column by adjacent cell value

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation, transpose

Is it possible to concatenate cells in a column dependent on values (`ID`) in another column, and then output as a string (possibly in another sheet as it would be cleaner)?

E.g.

```
ID          Text
1234        a
1234        b
1234        c
4321        a
4321        b
4321        c
4321        d
```

Output:

```
1234        a b c
4321        a b c d
```

Issues:

- Column IDs aren't in order (but can be sorted).
- Different amounts of each ID

This seemed like a possible `VBA` solution
from [How to merge rows in a column into one cell in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135995/how-to-merge-rows-in-a-column-into-one-cell-in-excel)

```
Function JoinXL(arr As Variant, Optional delimiter As String = " ")
    'arr must be a one-dimensional array.
    JoinXL = Join(arr, delimiter)
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
=JoinXL(TRANSPOSE(A1:A4)," ")
```

So I thought maybe if `INDEX` and `MATCH` etc could be used in conjuction with `TRANSPOSE` it could work. Just not sure how to go about it.

I can have a column of the unique IDs in another sheet.

Comment: Office 365 Excel has a new formula called TextJoin. You can use this in an array form to get what you want.

Comment: @ScottCraner Just looked it up now, looks like it would work. Unfortunately though, this needs to be working in Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is nice because it works even in cases where:

1. The text you're concatenating contains spaces.
2. You want to use a delimiter other than a space (ie a comma).

First, add "Transpose" to your custom function

```
Function JoinXL(arr As Variant, Optional delimiter As String = " ")
'arr must be a one-dimensional array.

arr = Application.Transpose(arr)
JoinXL = Join(arr, delimiter)

End Function
```

For [vertical arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKQKx.png), use this formula (replace comma+space with your delimiter of choice, and "{}" with your garbage characters of choice):

```
{=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(JoinXL(IF($A$2:$A$31=D3,$B$2:$B$31,"{}"),", "),"{}, ",""),", {}", "")}
```

For [horizontal arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HJjs.png), use this formula:

```
{=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(JoinXL(IF(TRANSPOSE($E$19:$AH$19)=D12,TRANSPOSE($E$20:$AH$20),"{}"),", "),"{}, ",""),", {}", "")}
```

Make sure you enter the formulas as array formulas (Ctrl+Shift+Enter after typing formula in cell).

Answer (score 1):

While no convenient function like your cited example, consider using a dictionary of collections with the ID column as the *key*. Below macro assumes data begins at *A2* (column headers in first row) with result outputting in *D* and *E* columns:

```
Sub TransposeValuesByID()
    Dim i As Integer, lastrow As Integer
    Dim valDict As Object
    Dim innerColl As New Collection
    Dim k As Variant, v As Variant

    Set valDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Range("A" & i) = Range("A" & i + 1) Then
            innerColl.Add Range("B" & i)
        Else
            innerColl.Add Range("B" & i)
            valDict.Add CStr(Range("A" & i).Value), innerColl
            Set innerColl = Nothing
        End If
    Next i

    i = 2
    For Each k In valDict.keys
        Range("D" & i) = k
        For Each v In valDict(k)
            Range("E" & i) = Trim(Range("E" & i) & " " & v)
        Next v
        i = i + 1
    Next k    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all you want is space between you can use your code with a couple changes.

If your data is Vertical you need to transpose the array to make it a one dimensional array:

```
Function JoinXL(arr As Variant, Optional delimiter As String = " ")
    'arr must be a one-dimensional array.
    arr = Application.Transpose(arr)

    JoinXL = Join(arr, delimiter)
End Function
```

If it is horizontal then use what you have.

The main change is how you call it.

Use the following array formula:

```
=TRIM(JoinXL(IF($A$2:$A$8=C2,$B$2:$B$8,"")," "))
```

being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

The If passes an array of values or blanks depending on if the cell is equal to the criteria.

Put this in the first cell Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then drag/copy down

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a work around, that although a little cumbersome works quite nicely.

Table has to be sorted by ID.

In another sheet.
ID: (Column A)

`1234`

MIN REF: (Column B)

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,OCCRANGE,0)+1,6)
```

MAX REF: (Column C)

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,OCCRANGE)+1,6)
```

RANGE: (Column D)

```
=CONCATENATE("'OCCS COMBINED'!",B2,":",C2)
```

STRING: (Column E)

```
{=IF([@[MIN REF]]=[@[MAX REF]],INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'OCCS COMBINED'!",[@[MIN REF]])),JoinXL(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(D2)), " "))}
```