# MS Excel, how to move text from one column into one cell?

Tags: excel

I have one column with items for example:

```
Column A:
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
item6
item7
item8 
..
```

All I would like to have one cell with text like:
`cell B1 = "item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8".` So every cell from Column A should be placed in one cell.

The problem is that sometimes i have 100 items. Please give me some smart advice :D

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge rows in a column into one cell in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135995/how-to-merge-rows-in-a-column-into-one-cell-in-excel)

Comment: What have you tried?  And what has been the problem with what you 've tried?  How does it differ from other, similar problems already with answers here on SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,A:A)
```

[image]